# How do I upgrade a Kubernetes worker node on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, windows-server-container

So I have a cluster with 3 CentOS 7 VMs (1 Master, 2 Worker) and 2 Windows Server 2019 worker nodes. I'm able to update the nodes on the CentOS VMs following this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/. Now, I need to update the version on the 2019 nodes and I can't figure out how to do it correctly. The version on the 2019 VMs are 1.14.3 (kubectl, kubelet and kubeadm) and I was able to upgrade them to 1.14.10 with no issues, but the moment I jump to the next major version (any 1.15.x), the kubelet service running under Windows services gets paused and obviously the node versions still show 1.14.10. Is the only way to upgrade the nodes is to recreate it and re-add it to the existing cluster? I haven't been able to find anything online besides the initial setup guides.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the target version?

Comment: Currently, any 1.15.x versions but I want to update to the latest version eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up recreating the node, which was faster and now it works on Windows.